# may I know why i am getting " not a statement " in this code?

Tags: compiler-errors

```
class test {
    static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int arr[] = { 23, 2, 73 };
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
            System.out.print(arr[i] + " ");

        System.out.println();

        int arr2[] = new int[3];
        arr2[] = { 23, 2, 73  };

        for (int i = 0; i < arr2.length; i++)
            System.out.print(arr2[i] + " ");

    }
}
```

just need to know the solution to remove the error!! and also why it arise!!?

Answer (score 0):

1. Java main functions must be `public`.
2. You are using C-style curly braces {} after array declaration.

> Java supports the C-style curly braces {} construct for creating an array and initializing its elements *when it is declared*  ([source](https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/java/exp/ch04_06.htm))

Replace

```
int arr2[] = new int[3]; arr2[] = { 23, 2, 73  };
```

with

```
int arr2[] = { 23, 2, 73 };
```

or

```
int arr2[] = new int[3];
arr2[0] = 23;
arr2[1] = 2;
arr2[2] = 73;
```

and the code will compile.